# Google Play Music Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension for chrome that makes an overlay appear on the Google Play Music site after you click a button. I can add a button just fine, but can't get a div to pop up above everything, it just gets shoved in at the bottom of the page.

I have these methods to add in the button and the div, they run just fine. The problem is the div is just stuck at the bottom of the page forever.

```
    injectCanvas: function( callback ) {
        var ivCanvas = $('<div />', {
            id: 'iv-canvas',
            style: 'top:0px;'
        //}).append( $('<img />', {
            //src: chrome.extension.getURL('images/icon.png')
        }).append('<span>Test</span');

        $('body').append(ivCanvas);
    },

    injectButton: function ( callback ) {
        var button = $('<button />', {
                id: 'iv-button-toggle',
                class: 'button small vertical-align'
            }).append('<span>Add Overlay Div</span>');

        button.on('click', function() {
            console.log("making visible");
            $('#iv-canvas').addClass('show');
            console.log("done making visible");
        });

        $('#headerBar .nav-bar').prepend(button);

        //callback();
    }
```

And here's the CSS I'm using to try and make the div visible

```
$canvas-background #141517;
#iv-canvas {    
  &.show {
        opacity: .8;
        background-color: $canvas-background;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1500;
  }
}
```

Am I going about this completely the wrong way? Can I create the div when the button is pressed instead of hiding and showing it?

Comment: Could you attach your popup.html code for us?

Comment: I was planning on creating the whole thing within this script, is that doable? All that is currently being generated is the <span>Test</span>. I'm far from an expert with any sort of web development so that could be my entire problem right there

Comment: You can't create the whole thing within one script because the default Content Security policy restrictions that inline JavaScript is not allowed. Keep in mind to move your JavaScript file to an external script file, and embed it in html file.